# How to force exact match of subdomains with NGINX?

Tags: docker, nginx, dns

I am using Nginx as a reverse proxy. It is running as a containerized service in a Swarm cluster.

A while ago I discovered this weird behavior and I'm trying to wrap my head around it.

On my host I have three subdomains set up:

- one.domain.com
- two.domain.com
- three.domain.com

In my Nginx server config I am specifying that the server_name I am targeting is three.domain.com, so I am expecting Nginx to only respond to requests targeting that subdomain.

```
events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {

  upstream service {
    server node:3000;
  }


  server {

    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name three.domain.com;

    [...... ssl settings here.......]

    location / {

      proxy_pass http://service;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
  }

}
```

What happens instead of only responding to requests sent to three.domain.com, it responds to one.domain.com and two.domain.com as well. (it routes them to three.domain.com)

If I add multiple server blocks specifically targeting subdomains one and two, it works as expected, it routes the requests where they belong.

That being said, the ideal behavior would be to only respond to subdomains which are listed in the server_name section of a server block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nginx tests the request’s header field “Host” (or SNI hostname in case of https) to determine which server the request should be routed to. If its value does not match any server name, or the request does not contain this header field at all, then nginx will route the request to the default server for this port. In your configuration above, the default server is the first (and only) one — which is nginx’s standard default behaviour. If there are multiple `server` blocks, it can also be set explicitly which server should be default, with the `default_server` parameter in the [listen](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen) directive

So, you need to add another `server` block:

```
server {
    listen      443 ssl default_server;
    server_name default.example.net;
    ...
    return      444;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your your answer Dusan! So basically all that is needed is a default server that will handle requests that have no matching server name.